# Add a Dummy Row for Each Row in the Table

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-data-explorer

I have below query which returns `%CPU` of each `Computer` by `every 1 hour`

### Query

```
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h) 
| where CounterName == "% Processor Time" 
| where Computer endswith "XYZ" 
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Computer
```

### Result

[image]

---

I want to append **Dummy** row for each-row in the table with **fixed value** except `TimeGenerated` should be same as previous row in the table.  Expecting result should look something like this.

### Expected Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this (note that you'll need to explicitly order your records as you wish):

```
let T = 
    Perf
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h) 
    | where CounterName == "% Processor Time" 
    | where Computer endswith "XYZ" 
    | summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Computer
;
T
| union (T | extend Computer = "Dummy", avg_CounterValue = 10)
| order by TimeGenerated
```

Comment: Sorry, I had attached wrong result screenshot.  I have attached screenshot of exact result.  Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: Just added `distinct` to the `union` and it worked.  Thank you so much.