# Azure Application Insights query to display time frequency

Tags: performance, azure, azure-application-insights, dashboard, azure-dashboard

want to Display the time along with milliseconds with the time duration like 1200 ms, 1500 ms on the Dashboard , Is there a way to define these time duration to display on chart?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRPQ8.png)

Comment: Please directly show the picture in the post, not show a link here:)

Comment: Please share sample query along expected results so can understand exact issue and provide solution accordingly.  Like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766644/add-a-dummy-row-for-each-row-in-the-table

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would work for you. But what I do when sharing a report from an App Insights or Log Analytics query, is use the `render * with(title="")` syntax to add a title. This allows me to add context to what it is I am sharing. For you this could be the place you specify the units of the X and Y axis.

See my example below for including titles.

```
let start = ago(3h);
let end = now();
let timegrain = 1m;
pageViews
| where 
    timestamp > start and timestamp < end
| summarize 
    Avg_Duration_Seconds = avg(duration)/1000 
    by 
    bin(timestamp,timegrain)
| render timechart with(title="AVG PageView Duration(seconds) - Last 3 Hours, By Minute")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to change the units in whatever chart that is however you got it on the dashboard.

If you did that query in workbooks, you'd go into chart settings in that step of the workbook and tell it the y-axis is milliseconds, and it would add the appropriate units for you in the labels.  If you are using metrics, the metrics should already know the units and show the right labels.

You'll need to clarify your question about exactly how / where you created that chart for anyone to help you any further.